# Select Statement based on user defined variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, case

I am trying to do a simple select statement based on the input of the user (SSRS). Help!

```
select * from Table1
WHERE
Case when @x = 'Yes' then (select * from Table1 where [Column1] < 0) end; 
case when @x = 'No' then (select * from Table1 where [Column1] > 0) end;
```

Thank you in advance

KJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
select * from Table1
WHERE
(@x = 'Yes' AND [Column1] < 0)
OR
(@x = 'No' AND [Column1] > 0);
```

By the way, `SELECT *` is really bad coding, you really should specify each column you are returning.

Comment: Thank you Declan K for the solution and feed back on my coding. I am still new to SQL and will definitely keep your advise in mind